# Docker Compose fails on copy

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a docker compose deployment but I have having an issue with the COPY that is in one of the projects. I have tried changing the path a few times without any luck. I continue to get the following issue:

```
ERROR: Service 'cryptoappapi' failed to build : COPY failed: file not found in 
build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat 
CryptoApp.Api/CryptoApp.Api.csproj: file does not exist
```

This is my layout

[image]

This is my docker file is standard:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CryptoApp.Api/CryptoApp.Api.csproj", "CryptoApp.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CryptoApp.Api/CryptoApp.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CryptoApp.Api"
RUN dotnet build "CryptoApp.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CryptoApp.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CryptoApp.Api.dll"]
```

This is my docker compose:

```
services:
  # First the AspNet Core app
  cryptoappapi:
    ## Get the image to use and set the container name
    image: cryptoappapi:latest
    container_name: cryptoappapi

    # State a dependancy on Redis working
    depends_on:
      - "redis_image"
      - "postgres_image"

    # Location of the Dockerfile
    build:
      context: ./CryptoApp.Api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    # Set access ports for localhost on the left
    ports:
      - "80:5000"
      - "443:5001"

    # Configure a link to Redis
    links:
      - "redis_image"
      - "postgres_image"

    # The Application needs a connection string for Redis, this just needs to be the Redis Service name as defined below
    # Pass it in as an Environmental Variable
    environment:
      - RedisConnection=redis_image
      - DB_CONNECTION_STRING="host=postgres_image;port=5432;database=xx;username=xxx;password=xxx"
    
    # Set them all to the same network
    networks:
      - dockerapi-dev
```

Comment: Can you please share folder structure at physical level ?

Comment: If your `build: { context: }` is the `CryptoApp.Api` directory, you don't need to also include that directory name when `COPY`ing in; just `COPY ./CryptoApp.Api.csproj` into the image tree.

Comment: @DavidMaze so if I remove that I get the next error Service 'cryptoappapi' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet build "CryptoApp.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: and this CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/CryptoApp.Api/CryptoApp.Api.csproj]

Comment: Added a COPY . . before the run now its happy

Answer (score 1):

In docker compose file, `build` can be specified either as a string containing a path to the build context or as an object with the path specified under `context` and optionally `Dockerfile`.

If you set context, this context is sent to the Docker daemon and compose built image from directory that you specified.

Also you don't need to include that directory name when COPY csproj to docker
If you dont want to change you docker file, you can edit your docker compose file and change your context to current directory and set full docker file directory.

```
services:
  # First the AspNet Core app
  cryptoappapi:
    ## Get the image to use and set the container name
    image: cryptoappapi:latest
    container_name: cryptoappapi

    # State a dependancy on Redis working
    depends_on:
      - "redis_image"
      - "postgres_image"

    # Location of the Dockerfile
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /CryptoApp.Api/Dockerfile

...
```

And also you can just change your docker file by this way if you dont want to change docker compose:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CryptoApp.Api.csproj", "CryptoApp.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CryptoApp.Api/CryptoApp.Api.csproj"
```